# Versionning a NodeJS project using GitLab CI not working in verify conditions section

Tags: node.js, version-numbering, semantic-release

**Hello Everyone,**

I'm trying to implement the versionning of a NodeJS project using GitLab CI but i have a strange problem when running npx semantic-release, could someone help me to resolve this problem.

**Error message :**

```
[12:42:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
 [12:42:29 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/gitlab] › ℹ  Verify GitLab authentication (https://GitLabURI/api/v4)
 2020-07-06T12:42:29.039Z semantic-release:gitlab apiUrl: 'https://gitLabURI/api/v4'
 2020-07-06T12:42:29.039Z semantic-release:gitlab repoId: 'bilel.krichen/NodeJSAPP'
 [12:42:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
 [12:42:29 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
     at module.exports (/builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/@semantic-release/gitlab/lib/verify.js:62:26)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
   pluginName: '@semantic-release/gitlab'
 }
 AggregateError: 
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
         at module.exports (/builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/@semantic-release/gitlab/lib/verify.js:62:26)
     at /builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:54:11
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
     at async Object.pluginsConf.<computed> [as verifyConditions] (/builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:80:11)
     at async run (/builds/bilel.krichen/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:84:3)
     at async module.exports (/builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:176:22)
     at async module.exports (/builds/bilel.krichen-sc/NodeJSAPP/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code
```

Could anyone help me please!

**Best Regards,**